# Do I need to install NPM in server to host a website built with Django Rest API and Vue JS?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I am newbie to Django. I have created a website ( similer to Quora) using Vue JS that consume Django REST API, I have used the Vue through Vue CLI. Do I need to install NPM in Heroku server to host the Vue CLI ?

I think the server may need large amount of space to host the NPM. Also running  NPM may impact the server speed. Should I consider CDN link of Vue JS instead of hosting in server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you do not need to install npm on the host machine. During development you need npm as you are serving and building your Vue app on the fly from your local machine. Vue CLI simply gives you a set of tools to get up and running.

When it comes time to deploy your code you need to build you Vue app into a set of static files. This can be done using the command.

```
npm run build
```

You will find this command when successfully run will give you a directory in your vue project called `/dist/`. The contents of this file is what needs to be served from heroku (statically).

I cannot give you more information than this as I do not know a huge amount about deploying static files to heroku, but it should give you the ground work to helping to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Matt Seymour. so after npm run build command the /dist/ file will contain vanilla javascript, is not it ?

Comment: When `npm run build` completes the `/dist/` directory will contain your application code in vanilla javascript. This is the code you need to upload to your herkoku instance